# create xml file with specific element and tag from a tree c#

Tags: c#, xml, tree

I have a Tree in my C# windows application that loaded from xml file.
I check some nodes in tree and then I want to create and save a xml file with checked tree nodes

Sample data in XML file

selected node must save in xml file with all elements and attributes.
thanks

```
<menu>
<item id="43BDF924-5E" text="System Management" system="010">
<item id="36A21901-45" text="Basic Information">
<item id="7FA03116-0F" text="Info">
<item id="74713E10-FF" code="AGM-D-1240-01" text="Persons"></item>
<item id="5373F379-E8" code="AGM-D-1260-01" text="Stock"></item>
</item>
</item>
<item id="36A21901-45" text="Google">
<item id="7FA03116-0F" text="sites">
<item id="74876E10-FF" code="MM-D-1240-01" text="Serch"></item>
<item id="0981F379-E8" code="MM-D-1260-01" text="Gmail"></item>
</item>
</item>
</item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            treeView1.Nodes.AddRange( new TreeNode[] {
                new TreeNode(
                    "id=\"43BDF924-5E\" text=\"System Management\" system=\"010\"", 
                    new TreeNode[] {
                        new TreeNode(
                           "id=\"36A21901-45\" text=\"Basic Information\"",
                           new TreeNode[] {
                               new TreeNode(
                                   "id=\"7FA03116-0F\" text=\"Info\"",
                                   new TreeNode[] {
                                       new TreeNode(
                                           "id=\"74713E10-FF\" code=\"AGM-D-1240-01\" text=\"Persons\""
                                        ),
                                        new TreeNode(
                                            "id=\"5373F379-E8\" code=\"AGM-D-1260-01\" text=\"Stock\""
                                        )
                                   })
                           })
                    }),
                 new TreeNode(
                     "id=\"36A21901-45\" text=\"Google\"",
                     new TreeNode[] {
                         new TreeNode(
                             "id=\"7FA03116-0F\" text=\"sites\"",
                             new TreeNode[] {
                                 new TreeNode(
                                     "id=\"74876E10-FF\" code=\"MM-D-1240-01\" text=\"Serch\""
                                 ),
                                 new TreeNode(
                                     "id=\"0981F379-E8\" code=\"MM-D-1260-01\" text=\"Gmail\""
                                    )
                         })
                      })
            });
            treeView1.ExpandAll();

            XElement menu = new XElement("menu");
            foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
            {
                XElement newChild = new XElement("item");
                menu.Add(newChild);
                CreateXmlElement(newChild, node);
            }
        }
        public void CreateXmlElement(XElement parentElement, TreeNode parentNode)
        {
            string pattern = "(?'name'\\w+)=\"(?'value'[^\"]+)";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(parentNode.Text, pattern);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                parentElement.Add(new XAttribute(match.Groups["name"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value));
            }


            foreach (TreeNode node in parentNode.Nodes)
            {
                XElement newChild = new XElement("item");
                parentElement.Add(newChild);
                CreateXmlElement(newChild, node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
Is there any approach to to insert attributes by code and dynamic.
the way you have done is static. if Xml file is changed code have to be changed. 
How can insert attributes of all node in xml to according node in tree dynamicly.Thanks

Comment: It is not static since I loaded the treeview then just to create test data.  All you need is the last part of the code which reads treeview and save to xml.  You can add option of only saving checked nodes.  I assumed you had the code to loaded the treeview.